# Django UpdateView with inherited models

Tags: django, inheritance, django-generic-views

I'm trying to use Django's generic UpdateViews with ModelForms, however I'd the model I'm using is an inherited model.

If I extend the UpdateView class when the model and form are bound to the 'BaseModel' everything works fine. I get 404 for instances that don't exist and can see and save data sucessfully.

If I extend the UpdateView class when the model and form are bound to the 'InheritedModel' the page will load but no data gets passed through and when I try to access a URL for an instance that doesn't exist, the page still loads the same.

models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):

    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CheckingAccount(Account):

    overdraft = models.IntegerField()
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^account/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', CheckingAccountUpdateView.as_view(), name='account-checking-edit'),
```

forms.py

```
class CheckingAccountForm(ModelForm): 

    class Meta: 
        model = CheckingAccount
```

views.py

```
class CheckingAccountUpdateView(UpdateView): 

    model = CheckingAccount
    form_class = CheckingAccountForm 
    template_name = 'account/checking_edit.html'
    success_url = '.'
```

Do generic class views such as UpdateView support inherited models? Am I missing something? If not, what is the best way to serve forms for inherited models?

Comment: Inheritance has nothing to do with it. There's something else going on. Post code.

Comment: Your CheckingAccount model subclasses Item rather than Account. What is Item?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it is subclassing from Account in practise.

Comment: Something else is going on. I pretty much copy-pasted your code and it works for me. http://dpaste.com/780236/